# Unable to access website with the "WWW" prefix

Tags: php, wordpress, dns

> **Backstory**: Website in question is [Mind of Steel](http://themindofsteel.com/) and uses WordPress. Everything was working fine. Website is set up to use naked domains (without *www*) but all pages were accessable either way (with or without *www*).

Yesterday, I was editing PHP files and setting up a proper child theme implementation. At one point, I did something rendering the whole site unloadable (an error in the PHP code which broke everything, though I'm still not sure what was the issue).

I reverted files I edited to the original Theme's code, then created new child-theme files, and everything works fine now, except one last issue:

**I can't access the website via "www.themindofsteel.com"**. If I enter the domain without the *www* prefix, everything loads fine.

From what I could tell, the problem seems to be local; test on [Down For Everyone or Just Me?](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/www.themindofsteel.com) shows that it's all fine. For me, however, most browsers (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) will return a blank page, and sometimes open the page normally on refreshing. Sometimes refreshing doesn't do a thing.

In Firefox, for example, I'm able to open the link normally the first time, but if I enter the same thing in another tab, it returns a blank page (no page title, no source code).

I tried logging out/logging in, clearing website cache, clearing local cache. The problem persists whether I am logged in or logged out.

I'm really baffled by this and don't know what might be causing this. Can anyone replicate the issue? How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you post the contents of your `.htaccess` file in the root directory?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan I'm not an expert, but from what I've found out ([link](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105950/is-it-safe-to-email-the-contents-of-your-htaccess)) it's not very safe to share the contents of my .htaccess file.

However, after looking at it, it pointed me in the right direction. After disabling a certain Cache plugin I've been using, the "www" issue dissapears on most browsers (can still replicate it in Safari). Not sure if that's the real issue and if Safari just has problems clearing cache.

Comment: it's difficult to solve the issue when we can't see the relevant code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make **.htaccess** file and add following code then save to your **public_html** folder in your web host.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, but after adding this code to my .htaccess file the problem is gone on all browsers I tested. Thanks!